# Qt::QTableWidget: SIGNAL currentCellChanged: Differ between mouse and keyboard

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget that emits the SIGNAL currentCellChanged calling a SLOT method whenever I select a row with the mouse or keyboard (tab or arrow keys). Is it possible to find out which one was used (mouse or keyboard)?

Comment: the `sender()` method of QObject will only get you to the QTableWidget, I think... you need to dig deeper than that to figure if it was provoked by mouse or keyboard... can't you do it the other way around? like, instead of having the QTableWidget emitting the signal and check the origin after, can't you make it emit the signal after onmouseclick or keypress events? that way you would know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a regular Designer form class and the table widget is part of that form.

In constructor of your form class you should do:

```
ui->tableWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Add `eventFilter` method to your class (it reimplements virtual `QObject::eventFilter`):

```
bool MyForm::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) {
  if (object == ui->tableWidget->viewport()) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
      method = method_keyboard;
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
      method = method_mouse;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In the slot you can check the value of `method` variable to find out which control was used.

Comment: My GUI is generated at runtime, but it works nevertheless. But KeyPress didn't work for tab, I had to use ShortcutOverride